# Show that $A\in\mathscr{B}(\mathscr{H}) and \|A\|=\sup_{n}\|A_{n}\|.$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

The following is the exercise 2.13 from Barbara MacCluer's Elementary Functional Analysis.

> Suppose $A_{n}\in\mathscr{B}(\mathscr{H}_{n})$ for $n=1,2,3,\dots$, where each $\mathscr{H}_{n}$ is a Hilbert space. Assume further that $\sup_{n}\|A_{n}\|<\infty$. Define $A$ on $\mathscr{H}\equiv\sum\oplus\mathscr{H}_{n}$ by $$A(h) =A(h_{1},h_{2},\dots)=(Ah_{1},Ah_{2},\dots).$$
> Show that $A\in\mathscr{B}(\mathscr{H})$ and $\|A\|=\sup_{n}\|A_{n}\|$. We call $A$ the direct sum of the operators $\{A_{n}\}$ and denote it $\sum\oplus A_{n}$.

I think by completeness of Hilbert space, it should simply follow as claimed, but I'm having trouble deductively showing the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: estimate the norm of $Ah$ using $\| (A_1 h_1 , A_2 h_2 ,...) \|^2 = \sum_j \| A_j h_j \|^2$ and boundedness of each of $A_j$.

Comment: $\| A(h) \|^2 = \sum_n \| A_n h_n \|^2 \leq \sum_n \| A_n \|^2 \| h_n \|^2 \leq (\sup_n \| A_n \|^2) \sum_n \| h_n \|^2 = (\sup_n \| A_n \|)^2 \| h \|^2$. Thus $\| A(h) \| \leq (\sup_n \| A_n \|) \| h \| $. This proves that if $\sup_n \| A_n \|$ is finite, then $A$ is bounded and $\| A \| \leq \sup_n \| A_n \|$. Can you see why the reverse inequality is also true?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using the squared norms instead of just norms? For the reverse inequality, I know that if $A$ is bounded below, then there exists some $\epsilon>0$ so that $\|Ah\|\ge\epsilon\|h\|$. Would I have to show that $\sup_n \|A_n\|$ is in fact smaller than $\epsilon$?

Comment: Using norms squared is convenient because of the identity $\| (h_1,h_2,...) \|^2 = \sum_n 
 \| h_n \|^2$. In Hilbert space calculations it is often the case that norms squared are easier to deal with than norms themselves. For the reverse inequality: put $S = \sup_n \| A_n \|$ and fix $\epsilon>0$. Then we can choose $n$ such that $\| A_n \| \geq S - \epsilon$ and $h_n \in \mathcal H_n$ with $\| h_n \|=1$ such that $\| A_n (h_n) \|  \geq ( \| A_n \| - \epsilon )$. Now put $h = (0 , 0 ,..., h_n, 0,...)$. We have $\|A h \|^2 = \| A_n h_n \|$, so $\| A \| \geq (S - 2 \epsilon)$.